# Change element class when radio button in checked with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have several block with the class `.form-group`.

When in this `div` it contains another class `.sub-question` and when the radio button is checked, how can I remove the class `.hide` ?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="container_radio">Choice A
        <input type="radio" name="q1[]" value="2" class="required">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="container_radio">Choice B
        <input type="radio" name="q1[]" value="3" class="required">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <div class="row sub-question hide">
        <h3 class="col-12">Item 1</h3>
        <div class="form-group col-12">
            <label class="container_radio">Answer 1
                <input type="radio" name="question_1[]" value="1">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-12">
            <label class="container_radio">Answer 2
                <input type="radio" name="question_1[]" value="1">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-12">
            <label class="container_radio">Answer 3
                <input type="radio" name="question_1[]" value="1">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event handler to the radio buttons that (if they are not part of a `.sub-question`) hides all `.sub-question` elements and then shows the `.sub-question` element associated with this radio button (if it exists):

```js
$('input:radio').on('click', function() {
  // find the parent form-group
  let parent = $(this).closest('.form-group');
  // only do something if this is not a sub-question
  if (parent.parent().is(':not(.sub-question)')) {
    // hide all sub-question
    $('.sub-question').addClass('hide');
    // show the current one
    parent.find('.sub-question').removeClass('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="container_radio">Choice A
        <input type="radio" name="q1[]" value="2" class="required">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="container_radio">Choice B
        <input type="radio" name="q1[]" value="3" class="required">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
  <div class="row sub-question hide">
    <h3 class="col-12">Item 1</h3>
    <div class="form-group col-12">
      <label class="container_radio">Answer 1
                <input type="radio" name="question_1[]" value="1">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-12">
      <label class="container_radio">Answer 2
                <input type="radio" name="question_1[]" value="1">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-12">
      <label class="container_radio">Answer 3
                <input type="radio" name="question_1[]" value="1">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First thanks for your help. To make it more generic, I used `$('input:radio')` but the problem is it activate the function on the secondary radio buttons too. How can I change this please? Thanks agin.

Comment: @popol that's why I had to add the `name^="q1"` qualifier on the event handler. If you need to be more generic you could perhaps use `$('input:radio.required')`?

Comment: can I just check if the `radio` has a `.sub-question` ?

Comment: @popol please see my edit. It checks whether a `radio` is not part of a `.sub-question` before showing/hiding elements